# Black screen on game launch

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to start a game when I click on "start game". Menu screen is removed and game launches (I can hear the sounds and then being killed by an enemy) but can't see a thing. All I get is a black screen. It's like the game is launched in the background.

What am I doing wrong ?

updated kv file:

```
<Game_Screen>:
    name: 'game_screen'
    on_enter: app.launch_game()

<Game_Menu>:
    FloatLayout:
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        size_hint: None, None
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Label:
            text: 'SPACE SHOOTER'
            font_size: 40
            font_name: "fonts/Alexis Italic.ttf"
            color: 0, 1, 0, 1
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 1.7}


        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            size: self.parent.size
            pos: self.parent.pos
            orientation: 'vertical'

            Label:
                text: 'menu'
                font_name: "fonts/Alexis Bold.ttf"
                font_size: 30
                color: 0, 1, 0, 1

            Button:
                text: 'start game'
                on_press: app.root.current = 'game_screen'
            Button:
                text: 'highest score'
                on_release: 
            Button:
                text: 'credits'
                on_release: app.root.current = 'credits'
```

updated Python code:

```
class Game(Widget):
    #  works fine on its own

class Game_Menu(Screen):
    pass

class Game_Screen(Screen):
    pass

class Menu_UI(Widget):
    pass

class Credits_Screen(Screen):
    pass

class GameApp(App):


    sm = ScreenManager()
    sm.add_widget(Game_Menu(name='menu'))
    sm.add_widget(Credits_Screen(name='credits'))
    sm.add_widget(Game_Screen(name='game_screen'))

    def launch_game(self):
        game = Game()
        Window.size = game.size
        engines1.loop = True
        engines1.play()
        return game


    def build(self):
        return self.sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GameApp().run()
```

Comment: what is Game_Menu and Credits_Screen? why launch_game returns main_widget?, you are creating the main_widget but you never set it to root.

Comment: I'll update the code so you can see more.

Comment: why instead of removing the screens, you add main_widget in another new screen ?, and in launch_game you make it move to that screen

Comment: Game_Menu and Credits_Screen are screen widgets. They make up the game menu. I'm struggling to properly launch the game 'coz apparently I haven't included it in root. Don't know how to do it.

Comment: You mean create another screen to switch to which will contain the game itself. Correct ?

Comment: yes that's what I mean.

Comment: That didn't occur to me. Will try that out.

Comment: use the on_pre_enter or on_enter event to start your game.

Comment: I updated the code. Believe or not still getting a black screen.

Comment: what is `Game()`, Is it a widget?

Comment: @eyllanesc  Yes, it is. I didn't include it here 'coz the Game(Widget) class is fairly extensive.

Comment: can provide a code that can run, I'm wasting time patching your code. read about [mcve]

Comment: The Game class works fine on its own. When I edit the `build` function to return Game() the game launches and everything is fine. It's that I can't launch it properly from that bloody game menu. I'm thinking of ditching it altogether.

Comment: I have not told you to provide the code of your project but you create another project similar but minimal.

Comment: If you do not provide a [mcve] I will not be able to test a solution, so I will only speculate on possible solutions, so bye, I do not want to waste any more time.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

[Programming Guide » Events and Properties » Main loop](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html)

> In Kivy applications, avoid long/infinite loops or sleeping. The
>   program will never exit your loop, preventing Kivy from doing all of
>   the other things that need doing. As a result, all you’ll see is a
>   ***black window*** which you won’t be able to interact with.

In your kv file, you have ***FloatLayout:***, Kivy will consider that as a root widget.

[Rule context](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html)

> The root rule is declared by declaring the class of your root widget,
>   without any indentation, followed by : and will be set as the root
>   attribute of the App instance.

## Solution

Use *Clock* schedule functions e.g. *schedule_interval()*, *schedule_once()*, or *create_trigger()* in replacement of long/infinite loops or sleeping.

1. Move codes for ***sm*** immediately after *GameApp* into the *build* method.
2. Indent all the codes after *<Game_Menu>*

### Snippets - main.py

class GameApp(App):

```
def launch_game(self):
    game = Game()
    Window.size = game.size
    engines1.loop = True
    engines1.play()
    return game

def build(self):
    self.sm = ScreenManager()
    self.sm.add_widget(Game_Menu(name='menu'))
    self.sm.add_widget(Credits_Screen(name='credits'))
    self.sm.add_widget(Game_Screen(name='game_screen'))
    return self.sm
```

### Snippets - game.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<Game_Screen>:
    name: 'game_screen'
    on_enter: app.launch_game()

<Game_Menu>:
    FloatLayout:
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        size_hint: None, None
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Label:
            text: 'SPACE SHOOTER'
            font_size: 40
            font_name: "fonts/alexisv3ital.ttf"     # "fonts/Alexis Italic.ttf"
            color: 0, 1, 0, 1
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 1.7}
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - AppStartup]

Comment: Sorry ... that indent is just a copy-pasting fault. I've got the indent correct on my end. The menu works fine but the when I click on "start game" the game launches with black screen. That's the problem I've been trying to fix for 3 days now.

Comment: I believed that you have long/infinite loop in your Kivy App and as a result, all you’ll see is a ***black window*** which you won’t be able to interact with.

Comment: Sorry this is little bit off-topic but I see you're using HP Assistant software on your Ubuntu. I've got HP laptop too and running Ubuntu I can't seem to find HP Assistant to download for Ubuntu. Where did you download it ?

Comment: The IDE that I am using is [PyCharm Community](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=linux) with [Kivy Auto Completion](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Setting-Up-Kivy-with-various-popular-IDE's) on Lenovo G50 laptop.

Comment: Oh. OK. I got confused by the HP icon in the taskbar then. I guess it's just a printer. Going back to our topic.